# Different height of element depending on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dimensions

i'm developing a site where i use jQuery to achieve a faux columns effect. Here is a test page: http://goo.gl/IL3ZB . The left yellow `<aside>` height is set in java script with the height of the `.body_container` div. The height is set correctly for display.

The problem is when i do in Firefox 17 a full refresh (Shift + F5) the `<aside>` is displayed correctly, with the correct height, but the animation in js sees a much smaller height. When i then refresh the page normally, then java script also sees the correct height.

How can i resolve this problem?

Here is my js:

```
var floating_patents_bottom = 0;


$(window).load(function(){
    $('.floating_patents').height( $('.body_container').height()  );
    floating_patents_bottom = ($('.body_container').height() > floating_patents_bottom ? $('.body_container').height() : floating_patents_bottom);
    var toBottom = {
        'top': floating_patents_bottom
    };
});

var toTop = {
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '500px',
    'display': 'none'
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.floating_patents').height( $('.body_container').height()  );
    floating_patents_bottom = ($('.body_container').height() > floating_patents_bottom ? $('.body_container').height() : floating_patents_bottom);
//    floating_patents_bottom = $('.floating_patents').height();

    var toBottom = {
        'top': floating_patents_bottom
    };

    var patents = $(".floating_patents img");
    patents.css(toTop);

    patents.each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(index * 5000).css('margin','10px auto').fadeIn("slow").animate(toBottom , 15000, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");
                });
    });
});
```

Comment: makes no sense to call this more than once `$('.body_container').height()`. Each time you call it, browser has to search the DOM to get the value... it is doing search numerous times instead of just once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when handler `$(document).ready` is called your images in content aren't fully loaded and have zero dimensions, so your `$('.body_container').height()` calculated incorrectly (the calculations sometimes happens correctly when browser takes images from the cache). The easiest solution for you is to move all code inside `$(window).load` handler.

A little refactored code which will work:

```
function floatingPatents() {
    // find required elements in DOM
    var patentsBlock = $('.floating_patents'), bodyContainer = $('.body_container');
    var patents = patentsBlock.find('img').hide();
    var floating_patents_bottom = 0;

    // wait for complete page load
    $(window).load(function(){
        // resize holder
        floating_patents_bottom = bodyContainer.height();
        patentsBlock.height( floating_patents_bottom );

        // calculate offsets
        var toTop = {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '500px',
            display: 'none'
        };
        var toBottom = {
            top: floating_patents_bottom
        };

        // start animation
        patents.show().css(toTop).each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(index * 5000).css('margin','10px auto').fadeIn("slow").animate(toBottom , 15000, function(){
                $(this).fadeOut("slow");
            });
        });
    });
}

// run code when page ready
$(floatingPatents);
```

Comment: Thx, the code works. Both answers are correct. I choose the one because of the code example.

Answer (score 0):

The document is ready before all of its elements are loaded. You're getting the correct height on the `$(window).load` event, but you're initializing the animations in the `$(document).ready` event. Just move everything into `$(window).load` and you should be good.

If waiting for the window to finish loading is too long (since otherwise, you won't be able to get the proper height of your `.body-container` div), you might be able to try this technique for getting placeholders for your images, so that the flow is correct before they've actually loaded.
http://andmag.se/2012/10/responsive-images-how-to-prevent-reflow/